# OpenGL extensions causing linker problems

Tags: c++, c, windows, opengl

I'm trying to get the addresses for the VBO addon. In my stdafx.h I have the gl.h, glext.h and wglext.h

If I do:
    glGenBuffersARB = 
        (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffersARB");
    glGenBuffersARB(0,0);

in stdafx.cpp, this will compile.
but if I try to use glGenBuffersARB(0,0); in any of my other h or cpp files I get:

```
Error   11  fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Vectorizer Project\Release\Vectorizer Project.exe
Error   10  error LNK2005: _glGenBuffersARB already defined in OGLENGINE.obj    stdafx.obj
```

what is the proper way of doing this so I can use the vbo extension anywhere in my code?

Thanks

Comment: GLEW might make your life easier and also make it easier to port your 
code if you ever decide to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> _glGenBuffersARB already defined

You probably declared glGenBuffersARB as a global variable in a header (*.h) file, and forgot to add "extern".

> what is the proper way of doing this so I can use the vbo extension anywhere in my code?

Use [GLEE](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/) or [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I second SigTerm. Managing extensions yourself is a tedious and error prone process...

Answer (score 0):

You have a linking error that looks like you have more than one definition for `glGenBuffersARB`. As a first debugging step I would change it so that the name of you function pointer is not the same as the name of the function that you are getting the address of.

```
fp_glGenBuffersARB = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffersARB");
```

It may be that the function is already defined with the name `glGenBuffersARB` in a library that you are linking to.

You don't show what context you are calling `wglGetProcAddress` or what scope your variable `glGenBuffersARB` (or `fp_glGenBuffersARB` following my rename) has but you must ensure the there is only a single definition for it. You can forward declare it in a header file but you must just have a single definition.